# Where does PHP Output go on MAMP

Tags: php, mamp

I'm running a MAMP server and printing data with the echo command in PHP to debug my scripts. I'm looking for where the log that contains this output would be located. It doesn't appear to be in the Apache access log or the PHP error log, so I'm not sure where else to look. Thanks!

Comment: `echo` outputs to the screen, not a log.

Comment: 1. Post some code. 2. `echo` goes to stdout. 3. stdout goes to the browser if you're invoking the script via HTTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others pointed out, `echo` goes to the browser. MAMP outputs PHP errors to `/Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log`. The function you're looking for is [`error_log('message')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php).

If we don't set the `message_type` or the `destination`, the

> message is sent to PHP's system logger, using the Operating System's system logging mechanism or a file, depending on what the [`error_log`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) configuration directive is set to.

Here's a [helper function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14543498) I use.