# Fatal error: Call to a member function render article() in GD Star Rating plugin for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I installed GD Star rating plugin few days ago, now I wanted to add new post, but I get error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function render_article() on a non-object in /wp-content/plugins/gd-star-rating/code/class.php on line 266
```

Line 266 is:

```
return $this->f->render_article($post, $userdata, $override);
```

All function is:

```
function shortcode_starratingblock($atts = array()) {
    global $userdata;
    $user_id = is_object($userdata) ? $userdata->ID : 0;
    $this->cache_posts($user_id);

    $override = shortcode_atts($this->default_shortcode_starrater, $atts);
    if ($override["post"] == 0) global $post;
    else $post = get_post($override["post"]);

    return $this->f->render_article($post, $userdata, $override);
}
```

Comment: You should contact the plugin author.

Comment: This problem is already posted  to him long time ago, I found it, but, he did not answered. I thought someone here may have some solution.

Comment: You'll have to add debug information: doing `var_dump( $var );`  until you find which one is failing and what it may contain that could help to fix it. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541989/how-do-i-debug-a-wordpress-plugin/14543498#14543498).

Answer (score 0):

Hello i recently had similar problem, Its because the Plugin Templates sql tables are corrupted . Please update the sql tables . 
Here is the code http://pastebin.com/9T0u3W6E

Run these queries through phpmyadmin.
Good luck