# How to print to standard input from WordPress custom plugin PHP code?

Tags: php, wordpress, logging

I am developing WordPress theme with lot of custom code. I am having hard time debugging as I don't know how to print/log messages in order to see them on the standard output i.e. terminal.

WordPress engine is running on OpenShift platform where I connect and look at standard output messages.

Comment: just add an exit or die() statement after you dump the data.  It will display the data and stop the script. Also use var_dump(), it shows more details. happy coding!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I debug a WordPress plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541989/how-do-i-debug-a-wordpress-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);` inside `wp-config.php`. This causes all errors to also be saved to the `/wp-content/debug.log`. The flag `WP_DEBUG` must also be enabled.

Comment: I already have debug logging turned on. How to throw error explicitly ? Or how to make assert statement that will cause the script to break if it is not satisfied ?

Comment: The easiest way is the one mentioned by @bwaaaaaa. You can use `var_dump($var);` method to output any $var. Also place a `die;` somewhere after that so you can see the results more easily. If you want more advanced debugging you can use xdebug php library. Better to see the instructions of your ide for this.