# Wordpress shortcode is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building an add-to-cart button that will place the item (pulled from XML code) into the cart. The `shortcodes` for the buttons are working and displaying the buttons, but when I try and implement the `shortcode function` to display the cart itself, the page doesn't render the buttons or cart at all. Here is some of the code I have (pretty new to PHP and Wordpress):

In the `shortcodes.php` file:

```
add_shortcode('show_cart', 'show_shopping_cart_handler');
```

In the `plugin.php` main file:

```
function show_shopping_cart_handler($atts) {
    return print_shopping_cart($atts);
}
```

In the `functions.php` file:

```
// code for pulling the XML, $product_id is attached to each button
$xml = simplexml_load_file("https://secure.bmtmicro.com/cart?CID=2/WP&PRODUCTID=' . $product_id . '") or wp_die("Error.");

function print_shopping_cart() {
 // handles the cart name/text
    if (!cart_not_empty()) {
        $empty_cart_text = get_option('cart_empty_text');
        if (!empty($empty_cart_text)) {
            echo '<div class="bmt_cart_empty_cart_section">';
            if (preg_match("/http/", $empty_cart_text)) {
                echo '<img src="' . $empty_cart_text . '" alt="' . $empty_cart_text . '" class="empty_cart_image" />';
            } else {
                echo __($empty_cart_text);
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
     }
     echo $empty_cart_text;

    $title = get_option('cart_title');

    echo '<div class="shopping_cart">';
    if (!get_option('shopping_cart_image_hide')) {
        $cart_icon_img_src = CART_URL . "/images/shopping_cart_icon.png";
        $cart_icon_img_src = apply_filters('cart_icon_image_src', $cart_icon_img_src);
        echo "<img src='" . $cart_icon_img_src . "' class='cart_header_image' value='" . (__("Cart")) . "' alt='" . (__("cart")) . "' />";
    }
    if (!empty($title)) {
        echo '<h2>';
        echo $title;
        echo '</h2>';
    }
    echo '<table style="width: 100%;">';
    if ($_SESSION && is_array($_SESSION)) {
        echo '
        <tr class="cart_item_row">
        <th class="cart_item_name_th">' . (__("Product Name")) . '</th><th class"cart_qty_th">' . (__("quantity")) . '</th><th class="cart_price_th">' . (__("Price")) . '</th><th></th>
        </tr>';
    foreach ($xml->producttable->row() as $product) {
      // I will pull more product info, but just using name for testing
        $product_name = $product->productname.PHP_EOL;

        echo '<tr class="cart_item_thumb"><td class="cart_item_name_td" style="overflow: hidden;">';
            echo '<div class="cart_item_info">';
            echo '<span class="cart_item_name">' . $product_name . '</span>';
            echo '<span class="cart_clear_float"></span>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</td>';
        }
    }

    echo "</table></div>";
}
```

Really what I am asking, can anyone see something that I may be doing wrong or missing that is causing nothing to display? I also tried to replace `echo` with `$output` and do things like `$output .= 'some HTML code';` and then run `return $output;`, but I still had the same result of a blank page.

I can supply some more code if needed, thanks in advance!

Comment: A shortcode should not `echo` anything, just return a string. Anyway, you need to debug what's happening, your current code is kind of impossible to reproduce... see [How do I debug a WordPress plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14541989/1287812)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$xml is not within scope of that function. You either need to pass it, define $xml within the function, or make $xml global. Plus, as brasofilo said, shortcode handlers should return a string, not echo. But since you mentioned that returning a string or echoing is producing the same thing then I would say the highest probability is an actual error. Like trying to iterate through an object that isn't defined as $xml is to that function.

Here's a crude example of what I mean...

```
function print_shopping_cart() {
    global $xml;
```

HOWEVER... $xml appears to rely on a product id, which we have no way to know how you are populating. For all we know, your $xml line is hitting the `or die` part and that's why you see nothing.

Now, officially I would say you should reconstruct how you handle this. You can define the shortcode directly in the plugin's php file.

in your plugin's php file:

```
add_shortcode('show_cart', 'show_shopping_cart_handler');

function show_shopping_cart_handler($atts) {
    // please note you're not using $atts. We dont know why
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('whatever');

    return print_shopping_cart($xml);
}
```

and in functions.php where we assume the shopping cart lives for a reason and not just because you wanted to unnecessarily complicate things, we actually pass $xml and modify the function to expect it...

```
function print_shopping_cart($xml = false) {
   if($xml)
   {
       return 'xml based string'; // now we know xml was successful
   }
   else
   {
       return 'deal with the cart some other way';
   }
}
```

In short, keep your plugin contained. If the plugin handles the whole cart then move everything to the plugin's php files and dont spread them all around. functions have a scope. If you try to access variables outside the function's scope it will throw an error or just outright "not do it." Your code above has a few holes in it that prevent us from really knowing what it is doing. We don't know how `$product_id` is populated. we don't know what `cart_not_empty()` does, etc. So this little example of mine is a way of giving a short example of how you can print a couple lines of text to begin your debugging. Slowly replace my example trash with your real code and find out where it breaks.

Comment: `$product_id` is used for each button (`[add_cart_button product_id=”22804″]`) and that ID is used to pull the information from our system. For the 'Buy Now' (one click button that redirects to our shopping cart, passing that ID to the URL which displays the proper product info) is working, but I had the issue trying to make the "Add to Cart" button to allow more than one product, etc. I will see what I can do with the info provided and hopefully get something working! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I commented out all of the other code inside the `print_shopping_cart` function and put what you had and it returned 'xml based string', so we're getting somewhere! @KaiQing