# Can't add a page in Wordpress after website migration (I changed my host file so I can work on my website before transforming to my new host )

Tags: json, wordpress, dns, hosting, database-migration

I changed my host file so I can work on my Wordpress website before my website is transforming to my new host. I had already make my website in Wordpress with the page builder: Elementor. So I used 'all in one migration' to migrate that website to this one. It migrated perfectly, but the only thing is that I can't add a page or post. When I want to publish I got an error thats says that he has no legit json reaction.

I think because the host file he can't handle sub url's, so when the website is transformed I can publish pages. Is this the problem or is the problem the migration?

I hope so someone can help me out.

thank you in advance!

Comment: this question might be better suited for [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Enable debugging and see what it shows https://stackoverflow.com/a/14543498/5193536