# Duplicate admin menu settings in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, admin

I am sorry if the title isn't correct, but I have no idea about those coding stuff I don't know how to explain it.

I am using WordPress and my theme has a build-in mega menu.
The problem is that the mega menu settings in admin panel appear twice while inside the file just one.

Example in screenshot below:

[image]

Here is the settings file:

```
<?php if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) { die; }

if(!class_exists('Veera_MegaMenu_Init')){

    class Veera_MegaMenu_Init{

        protected $fields = array();

        protected $default_metakey = '';

        public function __construct() {

            $query_args = array(
                'post_type'         => 'la_block',
                'orderby'           => 'title',
                'order'             => 'ASC',
                'posts_per_page'    => 20
            );

            $this->default_metakey = '_mm_meta';
            $this->fields = array(
                'icon' => array(
                    'id'    => 'icon',
                    'type'  => 'icon',
                    'title' => esc_html__('Custom Icon','veera')
                ),
                'nolink' => array(
                    'id'    => 'nolink',
                    'type'  => 'switcher',
                    'title' => esc_html__("Don't link",'veera')
                ),
                'only_icon' => array(
                    'id'    => 'only_icon',
                    'type'  => 'switcher',
                    'title' => esc_html__("Show Only Icon",'veera')
                ),
                'hide' => array(
                    'id'    => 'hide',
                    'type'  => 'switcher',
                    'title' => esc_html__("Don't show a link",'veera')
                ),
                'menu_type' => array(
                    'id'    => 'menu_type',
                    'type'  => 'select',
                    'title' => esc_html__('Menu Type','veera'),
                    'options' => array(
                        'narrow'      => esc_html__('Narrow','veera'),
                        'wide'  => esc_html__('Wide','veera')
                    ),
                    'default' => 'narrow'
                ),
                'submenu_position' => array(
                    'id'    => 'submenu_position',
                    'type'  => 'select',
                    'title' => esc_html__('SubMenu Position','veera'),
                    'info' => esc_html__('Apply for parent with "Menu Type" is "narrow"','veera'),
                    'options' => array(
                        'right'     => esc_html__('Right','veera'),
                        'left'      => esc_html__('Left','veera'),
                    ),
                    'default'   => 'right'
                ),
                'force_full_width' => array(
                    'id'    => 'force_full_width',
                    'type'  => 'switcher',
                    'title' => esc_html__('Force Full Width','veera'),
                    'info' => esc_html__('Set 100% window width for popup','veera')
                ),
                'popup_max_width' => array(
                    'id'    => 'popup_max_width',
                    'type'  => 'number',
                    'title' => esc_html__('Popup Max Width','veera'),
                    'after' => 'px',
                    'wrap_class' => 'la-element-popup-max-width'
                ),
                'popup_column' => array(
                    'id'    => 'popup_column',
                    'type'  => 'select',
                    'title' => esc_html__('Popup Columns','veera'),
                    'options' => array(
                        '1'         => esc_html__('1 Column','veera'),
                        '2'         => esc_html__('2 Columns','veera'),
                        '3'         => esc_html__('3 Columns','veera'),
                        '4'         => esc_html__('4 Columns','veera'),
                        '5'         => esc_html__('5 Columns','veera'),
                        '6'         => esc_html__('6 Columns','veera')
                    ),
                    'default'   => '4'
                ),
                'item_column' => array(
                    'id'    => 'item_column',
                    'type'  => 'text',
                    'title' => esc_html__('Columns','veera'),
                    'desc' => esc_html__('will occupy x columns of parent popup columns', 'veera')
                ),
                'block' => array(
                    'id'            => 'block',
                    'type'           => 'select',
                    'title'         => esc_html__('Custom Block Before Menu Item','veera'),
                    'options'       => 'posts',
                    'query_args'    => $query_args,
                    'default_option' => esc_html__('Select a block','veera')
                ),
                'block2' => array(
                    'id'            => 'block2',
                    'type'          => 'select',
                    'title'         => esc_html__('Custom Block After Menu Item','veera'),
                    'options'       => 'posts',
                    'query_args'    => $query_args,
                    'default_option' => esc_html__('Select a block','veera')
                ),
                'popup_background' => array(
                    'id'           => 'popup_background',
                    'type'         => 'background',
                    'title'        => esc_html__('Popup Background','veera')
                ),
                'tip_label' => array(
                    'id'        => 'tip_label',
                    'type'      => 'text',
                    'title'     => esc_html__('Tip Label','veera')
                ),
                'tip_color' => array(
                    'id'        => 'tip_color',
                    'type'      => 'color_picker',
                    'title'     => esc_html__('Tip Color','veera')
                ),
                'tip_background_color' => array(
                    'id'        => 'tip_background_color',
                    'type'      => 'color_picker',
                    'title'     => esc_html__('Tip Background','veera')
                )
            );

            $this->load_hooks();
        }

        private function load_hooks(){
            add_action( 'wp_loaded',                        array( $this, 'load_walker_edit' ), 9);
            add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item',           array( $this, 'setup_nav_menu_item' ));
            add_action( 'wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields',   array( $this, 'add_megamu_field_to_menu_item' ), 10, 4);
            add_action( 'wp_update_nav_menu_item',          array( $this, 'update_nav_menu_item' ), 10, 3);
            add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_title',              array( $this, 'add_icon_to_menu_item' ),10, 4);
            add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class',               array( $this, 'nav_menu_css_class' ),10, 4);
        }

        public function load_walker_edit() {
            add_filter( 'wp_edit_nav_menu_walker', array( $this, 'detect_edit_nav_menu_walker' ), 99 );
        }

        public function detect_edit_nav_menu_walker( $walker ) {
            $walker = 'Veera_MegaMenu_Walker_Edit';
            return $walker;
        }

        public function setup_nav_menu_item($menu_item){
            $meta_value = Veera()->settings()->get_post_meta($menu_item->ID, '', $this->default_metakey, true);
            foreach ( $this->fields as $key => $value ){
                $menu_item->$key = isset($meta_value[$key]) ? $meta_value[$key] : '';
            }
            return $menu_item;
        }

        public function update_nav_menu_item( $menu_id, $menu_item_db_id, $menu_item_args ) {
            if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {
                return;
            }
            check_admin_referer( 'update-nav_menu', 'update-nav-menu-nonce' );

            $key = $this->default_metakey;

            if ( ! empty( $_POST[$key][$menu_item_db_id] ) ) {
                $value = $_POST[$key][$menu_item_db_id];
            }
            else {
                $value = null;
            }

            if(!empty($value)){
                update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, $key, $value );
            }
            else {
                delete_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, $key );
            }
        }

        public function add_megamu_field_to_menu_item( $id, $item, $depth, $args ) {
            if(function_exists('la_fw_add_element')){
                ?>
                <div class="lastudio-megamenu-settings description-wide la-content">
                <h3><?php esc_html_e('MegaMenu Settings','veera');?></h3>
                <div class="lastudio-megamenu-custom-fields">
                    <?php
                    foreach ( $this->fields as $key => $field ) {
                        $unique     = $this->default_metakey . '['.$item->ID.']';
                        $default    = ( isset( $field['default'] ) ) ? $field['default'] : '';
                        $elem_id    = ( isset( $field['id'] ) ) ? $field['id'] : '';

                        $field['name'] = $unique. '[' . $elem_id . ']';
                        $field['id'] = $elem_id . '_' . $item->ID;
                        $elem_value =  isset($item->$key) ? $item->$key : $default;
                        echo la_fw_add_element( $field, $elem_value, $unique );
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        }

        public function add_icon_to_menu_item($output, $item, $args, $depth){
            if ( !is_a( $args->walker, 'Veera_MegaMenu_Walker' ) && $item->icon){
                $icon_class = 'mm-icon ' . $item->icon;
                $icon = "<i class=\"".esc_attr($icon_class)."\"></i>";
                $output = $icon . $output;
            }
            return $output;
        }

        public function nav_menu_css_class( $classes, $item, $args, $depth ){
            if(!is_a( $args->walker, 'Veera_MegaMenu_Walker' )){
                if ( $item->hide ) {
                    $classes[] = "mm-item-hide";
                }
                if ( $item->nolink ) {
                    $classes[] = "mm-item-nolink";
                }
                if ( $item->only_icon ) {
                    $classes[] = "mm-item-onlyicon";
                }
            }
            return $classes;
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please help me fix that? (Note: I am really newbie with those stuff, please be detailed)
I am sorry and thanks!

Comment: Honestly, it's hard to understand what exactly is an issue. What theme are you using? Is it your own custom made?\

You should check if you have hooked the mega menu twice somewhere, or the hook that is used in this class may be called somewhere twice.

Comment: Hello, the issue is that the menu settings are appearing twice. Check the image. I checked the other files I couldn't find something else. The theme I am using is called Veera.

Comment: `add_megamu_field_to_menu_item` hook is called twice. Search for it or something that is connected with it or the hook it is connected to and try to print some dummy debug data, to see at what point it happens. In your example above, there doesn't seem to be any issue. Maybe something other is filtering `wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields`? [Read this answer on how to debug WordPress plugin.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541989/how-do-i-debug-a-wordpress-plugin)

Comment: Hello, I found another file that is haveing the wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields Check: https://pastebin.com/Jb5Ymp2v

I am sorry I do not know how to do the things that you're telling me to do. :(
I can't see anything by using "WP_DEBUG", no errors in the browser console too.