# Woocommerce Product Data Section is messed up. How to resolve?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My wordpress website works fine but it's all messed up on the Add New Product Page. Specially Product Data Section and Variables. Contents are loading like lists shown in the attached image. Any way to solve this?

Thanks.

[image: Screanshot of the backend.]

Comment: do you get any console error?

Comment: No. everythings working fine. but it seems css error since everything is distorted.

Comment: Perhaps a conflict with a css rule in the `custom-editor-style.css` file? Do you use one?

Comment: No im not. What is the location of it?

Comment: In your theme but if you didn't add one there probably ain't one. you should probably disable plugins and more globally follow this thread to debug WooCommerce https://stackoverflow.com/a/14543498/3623080