# Why can the deactivation of Woocommerce plugin causes site crash?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem: on a Wordpress site I just deactivated woocommerce plugin and the whole site crashed... has this ever happened to you?

I tried to update the whole platform, uninstall the plugin from ftp and back-end, uninstall other useless plugins .... but I didn't get results

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more informations like a error message?

You need to change/add the following lines in the wp-config.php:

```
Example wp-config.php for Debugging

// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
```

More information about debugging in WordPress: [How do I debug a WordPress plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541989/how-do-i-debug-a-wordpress-plugin/14543498)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the whole site did not crash, from your question I can see that the admin site still works.

## The cause of the crash

You have uninstalled a plugin, namely Woocommerce. And from there on your public site becomes unresponsive. So there must be a connection between the two. You can be almost sure that some code you have still assumes Woocommerce to exist and causes the site to crash. It could be either in your own code or a plugin that you use.

## Error logs

You should turn on server error logging, then try to load the public page, see it crashing and check the logs. You should see errors along with stack traces, telling you the exact place of the error

## Preventing this problem in the future

While solving this problem either via server log tracking and fixing the issues one-by-one, for the future it would be good if you had a staging version of your website where you would perform these large operations, like plugin install and uninstall and then you would only risk downtime for the staging version of your site and once all the problems are solved, you can do the same at prod with significantly reduced risks.