# wordpress: is_serch() returns false in custom template

Tags: wordpress

I use this hook:

```
add_filter('template_include', 'custom_search_template');
function custom_search_template($template) {
    // Check if the 'type' parameter is present in the URL
    if (isset($_GET['type']) || isset($_GET['teacher']) ) {
        // Use 'search.php' as the template
        $new_template = locate_template(array('search.php'));
        if (!empty($new_template)) {
            return $new_template;
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
```

So when user visits mywebsite.com/type/blablabla the website uses search.php file. But it is weird that is_search () returns false. do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In the URL you provided "*mywebsite.com/type=blablabla*", are you passing it like this: `/type=blabala` or like this: `/?type=blablbal`?

because if you are doing it the first way as you stated in your question, then this is why it's returning false since adding `?` before the term `type` will use it as a parameter and work correctly. Instead, it will consider it as a **path** in the URL, and your first check in the function `if (isset($_GET['type']))` will return false because there was no parameter passed to the URL.

Plus, if you are uncertain of something, just try and log the info to the console by using the `error_log` function provided by WordPress and enabling Debugging mode on your website. [This might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14543498/15469806).

Comment: thanks. I made a mistake. I use it in this way:  mywebsite.com/type/blablabla

Comment: This is incorrect too `mywebsite.com/type/blablabla`, if you want to pass a parameter (query) you have to follow the correct syntax.
please read: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/http-the-definitive/1565925092/ch02s02.html